# Can Machine Learning Algorithms Process Contextual Features for Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, feature-engineering, interpolation

Take Figure 1 showing point interpolation, where point L0 is being interpolated using points L2 and L1 and the distances L11, L12, L21, and L22.

[image: Figure 1. Interpolation of point L0]

[image: Table 1. Dataframe representation for Figure 1.]

Whilst the graph shows a linear interpolation example, it is just to demo the idea whilst the Target variable is a product sum of arrays (non-linear)

Target/L0 = L1_Lag_Point * L11 + L1_Lead_Point * L12 + L2_Lag_Point * L21 + L2_Lead_Point * L22

Can a Machine Learning Algorithm understand that L11 is associated **ONLY** with Lagging Point L1, L12 with Leading Point L1, L21 with Lagging Point L2, and L22 with Leading Point L2?!

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. If you have formula for your interpolation points a machine learning can learn that formula yes. But its not clear what having a ML algo would achieve here.

Comment: @LucasMorin, a study on the ability of different ML algorithms to understand feature association.

Comment: Well that's the whole point of modern ML. However, as is, it not clear that your point are uniquely defined.

Comment: In the case of this interpolation problem for instance, the question is

Can a Machine Learning Algorithm understand that L11 is associated ONLY with Lagging Point L1, L12 with Leading Point L1, L21 with Lagging Point L2, and L22 with Leading Point L2?!

That is a close-ended question, answered in a Yes/No manner. I understand that the general answer is yes, but for instance in case simple linear regression, the answer is no.

Comment: your question is not clear enough for a human to understand how is the interpolation performed. If L12 is the middle point between L1 and L2, sure, there is a closed formula and a ML algo can learn that provided you have enough exemple. If the interpolation is more complex you'll need more info.

Comment: Please provide information on what you call interpolation, instead of those hand drawn arrows.

Comment: @LucasMorin 

L0 is the middle point between L1 and L2. I know there is a closed formula and an ML algo can learn. Which is the answer to the question actually. Except not every ML algo can learn. Like I said simple linear regression does not understand feature association.

The Hand Drown Arrows , is just to express feature association.

Comment: "Please provide information on what you call interpolation, instead of those hand drawn arrows."

The Hand Drown Arrows , is just to express feature association but 
Sure , no problems , here :
Target = 
L1_Lag_Point * L11 + 
L1_Lead_Point * L12 + 
L2_Lag_Point * L21 +
L2_Lead_Point * L22

Comment: I am still not sure what your question is... yeah some algo can't learn that and need feature engineering. And some algo can, typically NN are universal function approximator (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem), trees too. In practice it can get a bit more complex as you need minimal amount of data and uncorrelated points.

Comment: And there is still a question remaining: why would you do that in the first place? Sure I can link you to universal approximation theorem, but it's not clear why you would want to use ML to learn a mostly linear function (which is already an exact model of what you want to achieve).

Comment: yeah some algo can't learn that and need feature engineering. There you just gave your answer. Whilst it is a common knowledge for you maybe, it is still informative for learning about the different scenarios a simple linear algorithm would fail. This one included.

Comment: And there is still a question remaining: why would you do that in the first place? 
Because most non-linear ML algos are super slow, whilst I prefer using linear ones, they come with limitations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151089/discussion-between-emad-ezzeldin-and-lucas-morin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will borrow Luca Morin's answer from the comments :

"yeah some algo can't learn that and need feature engineering. And some algo can, typically NN are universal function approximators (see: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem), trees too."

Almost all non-linear ML Algorithms can understand Feature Association, but they are much slower than linear ones. Thus Feature Engineering like adding interaction and high-order features with Linear Algorithms is recommended. Would recommend for scikit-learn poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2,interaction_only=True,
include_bias=False) for adding interactive features.

Keeping in mind that whilst the graph shows a linear interpolation example, it is just to demo the idea whilst the Target variable is a product sum of arrays (non-linear), and thus a linear solution will not fit well without feature engineering mentioned in the above paragraph.