# Can Linear Models infer Product Sum operation of Features to predict Target?

Tags: linear-regression, linear-models

In a dataset of 9 columns: $X_1-X_8, y$.

$y = X_1 * X_5 + X_2 * X_6 + X_3 * X_7 + X_4 * X_8$

Can any form of linear model (anything but SVM, NN, Random Forest, XGBoost, etc.) predict $y$?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @LucasMorin  , No 

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/126504/can-machine-learning-algorithms-process-contextual-features-for-regression

Answer (score 1):

Only by adding interaction features like multiplication/division/powers..etc. of Features. However, then be sure to cross-validate and test on 0.2 of data size to factor for overfitting.